# PHP: ParseCSV or PHPExcel which is better?

Tags: php, excel, export-to-csv

I want to create an application that when you import the CSV then it will export to .xlsx. But there are some conditins:

1. I need to change the column order and remove some of the columns when its exported
2. I need also to change the color and font(size,color)
3. And also create a multiple worksheets on single .xlsx file.

Which is better to use on this kind of application, can anybody help me and share some points which is better. I do the exploring on both but I need some guidance and some better solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('First Name', 'Last Name'));
```

You dot need to use a plugin or anything. PHP has the functionality within itself. What i wrote above is an example of defining the file and outputting the first row of the CSV.

Each use of `fputcsv()` outputs a new row.

So you can define the order of things by telling it in the array which value goes where in the row.

Comment: but my concern is base in the 3 condtions. How can I change the color or font size ? But thanks on your answer man.,

Comment: @frogcoder CSV stands for comma seperated values. You can't achieve this because CSV file doesn't support font styles etc.

Comment: yup its not. but if you read the csv and parse it , as an array and export it at .csv